# Google Cloud Platform autoscaling group memory consumption

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I would like to scale mi instance group by memory usage but I couldn't find the options. I installed the agent within the windows VM and I can see metrics on Stack drive panel but on autoscaling group panel I can't see metrics at all.